# Bloom is different in Inspector vs Game view Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, post-processing

So basically I'm using the lighting system for the 2D render pipeline in Unity, and for whatever reason the post processing looks different in either view.
[Pictured Here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEoTv.png) The scene view has more glow than the game view, and I would very much like to have the sceneview show up in game, anyone know how to do so?

Edit: I have figured out that my game view is not using scene lighting, as when I turn off scene lighting in my scene view, both cameras are identical.

Edit: So apparently my game view is using lighting, but not the bloom effect.

Comment: `The Inspector view` .. I think you mean the `Scene View` since the Inspector is the thing on the right ;) And they are most of the time different since as you can see the gameView has a total different background and also the lightning is different in the SceneView so you can usually still see the objects also if there is no lights at all ... This is somewhere adjustable afaik

Comment: Yeah I meant the scene view- I'll fix that. Thanks for the insight bro.

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up figuring out that if you go to the Render Pipeline asset and go under Quality, checking the HDR checkmark under it does what I'm looking for

[Pictured Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm3hY.png)